# Put 3 photos side by side in the middle of my page

Tags: html, css

Okay so I saw this tutorial on youtube on how to put side nav bar that pops up when hovered,and when I click it it brings me to the designated div with smooth scrolling. My divs are home,partylists,candidates,vote and result. It's all located in one web page it scrolls vertically. It works perfectly. Now I want to put 3 photos on the candidate div,in the middle of the page. How can I do it?

Comment: where is your code ? just upload what u have tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please take a moment to check out how to ask your question so that you can get some helpful answers >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Flexbox, apply it to the div in which you want to put the images.

In your CSS file:

```
div {
     display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
     }
```

Hope this helps you!